# Facebook and public page content

Tags: facebook, permissions, token

I'm developping a website in which a user gives an url's public facebook post (he is the owner) and my server retrieves the photo attached to that post.

According the facebook doc, I understand that I need to create an app and my server uses the app's credentials to communicate with facebook.

That app needs permission: 'Page Public Content Access' I believe...

My question is: do I need the user's authorization (user access token after login process) to access the photo of the post?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If it is a user post then yes you need the users permission. If it is a page then no you don't need the page permission if you have Page Public Content Access

Comment: Thanks for your reply !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I answer my own question to complete @WizKid comment.
Effectively in that case, if it's a user post, user_photos permission is necessary else for a page, Page Public Content Access is necessary.
One important thing to add is about app review: when you ask for permissions or features the use cases of your app must be one of the allowed usage. Permissions:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions and features: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/features-reference